# Right SSH key is automatically picked up

Tags: security, ssh, server, digital-ocean

I created a new DO droplet and generated new ssh key pairs for it using `ssh-keygen`, then uploaded the public key to my droplet. In my user's `.ssh` folder i have 3 ssh key pairs. The problem is that i am able to log into my server passing any key as parameter for `-i`, like for example, if i do `ssh user@domain.com` i can successfully log in, even though, the public key in my server is **NOT** `id_rsa.pub`. I can also do `ssh -i .ssh/another_key user@domain.com` and that works too. Seems as if as long as the key is in the `.ssh/` folder, i don't need to specify it, as it picks it up automatically, but i don't know if that's normal behavior and i cannot find anything in the docs. Should i worry about this? I don't get ssh sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh` will try several (in fact, up to three) private keys when you're trying to connect to a server.

If you run `ssh -v user@domain.com` you should see output like this:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

that is `ssh` trying keys from your `~/.ssh/` directory.

Comment: Yeah, thanks man that clears things up, i was freaking out for nothing